# PHONEGAP APK version can't send and retrieve data from server

Tags: ajax, build, phonegap

I am a beginner in Android programming. I have a problem with CORS security policy. The application runs fine and normal in PHONEGAP Developer for Android, but the application does not run properly when the build APK release. Anyone can help me.

**index.html**

```
... <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">...
...<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js" ></script>...
...$.ajax({
        type: "POST",crossDomain: true, cache: false,
        url: "http://example.com/process.php",
        data:{"category":"book"},
        success: function(data){    
            alert(data)       
        },
            error: function(){
            alert(error);
            }
    });...
```

**config.xml**

```
...<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.3.4" />...
...<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />...
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />...
```

**Build log APK**

```
    Build Date: 2020-08-06 00:21:43 +0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PLUGIN OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device@~1.1.6" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" at "1.1.7" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-dialogs@~1.3.3" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-dialogs" at "1.3.4" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file@~4.3.3" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" at "4.3.3" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-compat@^1.0.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" at "1.2.0" for android

The Android Persistent storage location now defaults to "Internal". Please check this plugin's README to see if your application needs any changes in its config.xml.

If this is a new application no changes are required.

If this is an update to an existing application that did not specify an "AndroidPersistentFileLocation" you may need to add:

      "<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />"

to config.xml in order for the application to find previously stored files.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-geolocation@~2.4.3" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" at "2.4.3" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on android.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@~1.7.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" at "1.7.2" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-network-information@~2.0.2" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-network-information" at "2.0.2" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-cors@~1.0.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-cors" at "1.0.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@~1.3.4" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" at "1.3.4" for android
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROJECT PROPERTIES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
# Project target.
target=android-25
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILE OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Could not initialize analytics, treating as opt-out.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /.android/analytics.settings (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.saveSettings(AnalyticsSettings.java:266)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.createNewAnalyticsSettings(AnalyticsSettings.java:202)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ProcessRecorderFactory.initializeAnalytics(ProcessRecorderFactory.java:196)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ProcessRecorderFactory.get(ProcessRecorderFactory.java:220)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ProcessRecorderFactory.initialize(ProcessRecorderFactory.java:122)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfilerInitializer.init(ProfilerInitializer.java:66)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.java:310)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.java:75)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at build_8tzjah0b3soj8j450dh9ulzvu.run(/var/gimlet/tmp/3677609/project/build.gradle:39)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:176)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:181)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_8tzjah0b3soj8j450dh9ulzvu.run(/var/gimlet/tmp/3677609/project/build.gradle:156)
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
The ProjectDependency.getProjectConfiguration() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
ModuleDependency.getConfiguration() has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Use ModuleDependency.getTargetConfiguration() instead.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
:CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease
:prepareProjectCordovaLibUnspecifiedReleaseLibrary
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:processReleaseManifest
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /var/gimlet/tmp/3677609/project/src/org/apache/cordova/file/AssetFilesystem.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseSources
:mergeReleaseShaders
:compileReleaseShaders
:generateReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:packageRelease
:assembleRelease
:cdvBuildRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.803 secs
Built the following apk(s): 
    /var/gimlet/tmp/3677609/project/build/outputs/apk/project-release-unsigned.apk
Starting application signing
updating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   adding: META-INF/LSTECH.SF
   adding: META-INF/LSTECH.RSA
  signing: AndroidManifest.xml
  signing: assets/www/config.xml
  signing: assets/www/cordova.js
  signing: assets/www/cordova_plugins.js
  signing: assets/www/cors.php
  signing: assets/www/index.html
  signing: assets/www/jquery.min.js
  signing: assets/www/phonegap.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-dialogs/www/android/notification.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-dialogs/www/notification.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryEntry.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryReader.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Entry.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/File.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileEntry.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileError.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileReader.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileSystem.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileUploadOptions.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileUploadResult.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Flags.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/LocalFileSystem.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Metadata.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/ProgressEvent.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/android/FileSystem.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/browser/isChrome.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystemPaths.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems-roots.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/requestFileSystem.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/PositionError.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/android/geolocation.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-network-information/www/Connection.js
  signing: assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-network-information/www/network.js
  signing: assets/www/process.js
  signing: classes.dex
  signing: res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_action_next_item.png
  signing: res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_action_previous_item.png
  signing: res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_action_remove.png
  signing: res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_action_next_item.png
  signing: res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_action_previous_item.png
  signing: res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_action_remove.png
  signing: res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_action_next_item.png
  signing: res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_action_previous_item.png
  signing: res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_action_remove.png
  signing: res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_action_next_item.png
  signing: res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_action_previous_item.png
  signing: res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_action_remove.png
  signing: res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/icon.png
  signing: res/mipmap-ldpi-v4/icon.png
  signing: res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/icon.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/icon.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/icon.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/icon.png
  signing: res/mipmap/icon.png
  signing: res/xml/config.xml
  signing: resources.arsc
jar signed.

Warning: 
The signer's certificate is self-signed.
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2045-07-28) or after any future revocation date.
Finished application signing
Verifying alignment of /var/gimlet/tmp/3677609/project/build/outputs/apk/project-release.apk (4)...
      50 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (OK - compressed)
    2183 META-INF/LSTECH.SF (OK - compressed)
    4416 META-INF/LSTECH.RSA (OK - compressed)
    5582 AndroidManifest.xml (OK - compressed)
    6799 assets/www/config.xml (OK - compressed)
    8257 assets/www/cordova.js (OK - compressed)
   25817 assets/www/cordova_plugins.js (OK - compressed)
   26788 assets/www/cors.php (OK - compressed)
   27048 assets/www/index.html (OK - compressed)
   28799 assets/www/jquery.min.js (OK - compressed)
   59209 assets/www/phonegap.js (OK - compressed)
   76794 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js (OK - compressed)
   78188 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-dialogs/www/android/notification.js (OK - compressed)
   79258 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-dialogs/www/notification.js (OK - compressed)
   81116 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryEntry.js (OK - compressed)
   82661 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryReader.js (OK - compressed)
   83882 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Entry.js (OK - compressed)
   86423 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/File.js (OK - compressed)
   87694 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileEntry.js (OK - compressed)
   89142 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileError.js (OK - compressed)
   90022 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileReader.js (OK - compressed)
   93206 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileSystem.js (OK - compressed)
   94279 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileUploadOptions.js (OK - compressed)
   95258 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileUploadResult.js (OK - compressed)
   95976 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js (OK - compressed)
   98713 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Flags.js (OK - compressed)
   99534 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/LocalFileSystem.js (OK - compressed)
  100197 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Metadata.js (OK - compressed)
  101044 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/ProgressEvent.js (OK - compressed)
  102269 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/android/FileSystem.js (OK - compressed)
  103345 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/browser/isChrome.js (OK - compressed)
  104111 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystemPaths.js (OK - compressed)
  105319 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems-roots.js (OK - compressed)
  106244 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems.js (OK - compressed)
  106963 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/requestFileSystem.js (OK - compressed)
  108327 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js (OK - compressed)
  110019 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/PositionError.js (OK - compressed)
  110843 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/android/geolocation.js (OK - compressed)
  111942 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js (OK - compressed)
  113510 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-network-information/www/Connection.js (OK - compressed)
  114268 assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-network-information/www/network.js (OK - compressed)
  115708 assets/www/process.js (OK - compressed)
  116196 classes.dex (OK - compressed)
  213060 res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_action_next_item.png (OK)
  213424 res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_action_previous_item.png (OK)
  213780 res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_action_remove.png (OK)
  214096 res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_action_next_item.png (OK)
  214408 res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_action_previous_item.png (OK)
  214716 res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_action_remove.png (OK)
  214988 res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_action_next_item.png (OK)
  215384 res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_action_previous_item.png (OK)
  215776 res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_action_remove.png (OK)
  216124 res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_action_next_item.png (OK)
  216596 res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_action_previous_item.png (OK)
  217068 res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_action_remove.png (OK)
  217472 res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/icon.png (OK)
  226468 res/mipmap-ldpi-v4/icon.png (OK)
  229448 res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/icon.png (OK)
  234064 res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/icon.png (OK)
  248152 res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/icon.png (OK)
  275412 res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/icon.png (OK)
  317548 res/mipmap/icon.png (OK)
  322153 res/xml/config.xml (OK - compressed)
  323564 resources.arsc (OK)
Verification succesful
```

**process.php**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');...
```

We have also signed the APK file, but we still can't access the server even though we have installed the signed APK on smartphone

**Log APK alignment**

```
Aligning "example-release.3677609.56_SIGNED_UNALIGNED.apk" (4)...

             50  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  (Compressed, Passed)
          ...
          5,581  AndroidManifest.xml  (Compressed, Passed)
          6,798  assets/www/config.xml  (Compressed, Passed)
          8,256  assets/www/cordova.js  (Compressed, Passed)
         25,816  assets/www/cordova_plugins.js  (Compressed, Passed)
         26,787  assets/www/cors.php  (Compressed, Passed)
         27,047  assets/www/index.html  (Compressed, Passed)
         28,798  assets/www/jquery.min.js  (Compressed, Passed)
         59,208  assets/www/phonegap.js  (Compressed, Passed)
         76,793  assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js  (Compressed, Passed)
         ...
         86,422  assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/File.js  (Compressed, Passed)
         87,693  assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileEntry.js  (Compressed, Passed)
        ...                        
        110,018  assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/PositionError.js  (Compressed, Passed)
        110,842  assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/android/geolocation.js  (Compressed, Passed)
        111,941  assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js  (Compressed, Passed)
        113,509  assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-network-information/www/Connection.js  (Compressed, Passed)
        114,267  assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-network-information/www/network.js  (Compressed, Passed)
        115,707  assets/www/process.js  (Compressed, Passed)
        116,195  classes.dex  (Compressed, Passed)
        213,056  res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_action_next_item.png  (Compressed, Passed)
        ...
        317,526  res/mipmap/icon.png  (Aligned, 2 B)
        322,131  res/xml/config.xml  (Compressed, Passed)
        323,542  resources.arsc  (Compressed, Passed)

Alignment done, output file: "example-release.3677609.56_SIGNED_ALIGNED.apk"
```

Comment: Please add the error message to the post, it's not clear what is happening with the information you are passing. Maybe the APK is not working because you need to generate a signed APK.

Comment: okay ... I have displayed the build log

Comment: Try connecting the Remote Debugger to your app. You'll need to have the device connected to your computer. You can then look at the Console tab and see the actual error messages. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try first.